# Save game/user statistic in a central database with swift and sql on IOS 8

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite, swift

I am making a game for IOS 8 using the Swift language. For each level I was planning to save data such as how long it takes to solve the level, what (x,y) position a player dies, how many attempts before solving the level etc. I will then use this information to improve the game by adjusting the difficulty of levels.

So I figured I would have a simple SQlite DB stores locally with this information. And then I wonder how I should upload this information to one central database. Any ideas?

For example, what kind of unique identifier can I use? I don't care about the individual data, just the average time to complete a level and the average nr of attempts to solve a level..

But, if I have in-app purchases, how can a user that delete the app, or get another iphone restore the purchases made? This is again related to a unique identifier that is connected to the user, not just the iphone.

Comment: This is what Core Data is for.

Comment: I suggest using NSDefaults to store your game data. You can easily access the info without passing it from scene to scene. I'm not sure about the unique ID.

Answer (score 0):

You really should be using analytics tools to do this.  I would recommend using Flurry.  Its free to use, and goes into your game very easily.

http://www.flurry.com/solutions/analytics

I have used it in a number of products.  You can send in the anonymous data you want based on events.  So every time a level is complete, you can report it to flurry as an event, and pass parameters of level, score, and completion time.

You can look at a nice dash board to see the results and averages.

Its easy to incorporate it into a Swift app.  [Another SO answer goes through this in detail.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26198199/793607)