# how to integrate flurry in ios using swift language

Tags: ios

I want to integrate flurry in ios using swift language.
I added the flurry sdk's two files : flurrylib.a and flurry.h and then entered my api key in project TestProject4-Bridging-Header.h

```
#import "Flurry.h"
```

Answer (score 19):

I had the same issue and adding a bridging header worked for me. Here are the steps I followed.

Note: If you already have a bridging file, skip the steps 2 to 4

1. I dragged the Flurry folder to my Swift iOS project in XCode.
2. I created a bridging header file by creating a new Objective-C header file (in XCode menu it's File/New/File/iOS/Source/Header File)
3. I called the file name "PROJECTNAME-Bridging-Header.h" (replace PROJECTNAME with your XCode project name)
4. In Project Build Settings, I searched for "Swift Compile - Code Generation" and there in "Objective-C Bridging Header" I entered the name of my new bridging file (PROJECTNAME-Bridging-Header.h) for debug and release values.
5. Now, back in my bridging header file, I referenced the Flurry header file.

   `#import "Flurry.h"`
6. In my AppDelegate.swift file, I could then call the Flurry methods using Swift:

   `func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
   // setup Flurry
   Flurry.startSession(flurryKey)         // replace flurryKey with your own key
   Flurry.setCrashReportingEnabled(true)  // records app crashing in Flurry
   Flurry.logEvent("Start Application")   // Example of even logging`

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: I had to add SystemConfiguration.framework to make it compile without errors.

Answer (score 3):

**Flurry Integration using Pods in Swift**

You need to import Flurry SDK as Follows

```
import Flurry_iOS_SDK

 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
         Flurry.startSession("YOUR_API_KEY")
         Flurry.logEvent("Started Application")
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are attempting to log events in the 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions' using Flurry SDK 6.0.0, this is not possible due to a bug in that version of the SDK.  It is possible to start a session from this function however. I was told this information by a Flurry support rep, and confirmed it in my own testing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a bridging header to your project. In that bridging header you import what you need in Swift and then you don't need to import it anywhere else.
The iBook on using Swift and Obj-C alongside has a very good explanation on this.

Actually, there is an explanation on Apple's Swift blog that says:

> To be safe, all components of your app should be built with the same version of Xcode and the Swift compiler to ensure that they work together.

You can find more information [here](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=2).

Comment: I am doing the same thing but Flurry is not integrating error is no such module

Comment: There is a build setting 'Defines Modules'. You might have to change that to YES. Also, I seem to remember from on of the WWDC sessions, that it is either recommended or required to compile everything in the project in one build. This means that you can only include libraries for which the source code was compiled together with your swift-code, and for this you would need Flurry's source code. So I guess you are out of luck. Try to look for 'binary compatibility swift', and i am sure you will find your answer.

Comment: I edited my original answer with an actual answer, and a link to where to find more info.